# Automorphisms of finite order on $K3$ surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

> Is there a $K3$ surface (algebraic, complex) that has *infinitely* many automorphisms of *finite* order?

Many K3 surfaces have infinite automorphism groups.
In particular, all  K3 surfaces  of Picard rank 20 have infinite automorphism groups.
However, the above question is unclear to me.

Comment: Does conjugating a finite order automorphism by every element of an infinite automorphism group not do the trick?

Comment: Cojugating by a commuting element does not give a new automorphim. It is unclear to me that conjugating shall give *infinitely* many  *different* automorphisms.

Comment: To give a concrete example: a hypersurface of degree $(2,2,2)$ in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ contains a subgroup $G$ isomorphic to the free product of 3 groups of order 2 , hence containing infinitely many elements of order 2.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick answer!